# Determining 64-bit vs. 32-bit Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'd like to configure visual studio 2005 to copy .dll's based on whether the OS is 64-bit or 32-bit during a build.

I do not want to specify what the platform target is.

My first attempt was to use a batch file to lookup the Windows version, but some 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows share the same version number.

Anyone know of any way to check this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to read the environment variable %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%. Here is some great information on it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/HOWTO-Detect-Process-Bitness.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Check out [isWow64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx), I think that shopuld give you what you are after.

> Determines whether the specified process is running under WOW64.

Comment: I don't think that will be useful in the context of the question -- he doesn't want to write a C program; he just wants to copy some files during a builld.

Answer (score 2):

Jon's link is a total hack because it relies upon no new processor architectures being added.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556009 for the "official" batch file method.

Comment: This method is also not fooled by environment virtualization when a script is run using a 32-bit version of CSCRIPT.EXE/WSCRIPT.EXE on a 64-bit machine. It correctly reports what the processor *actually is*, instead of what SYSWOW64 *says* it is.