# How can my Perl script know it is running under Win64?

Tags: perl, winapi, registry, win64

How can I have my Perl script detect it's running on a 64-bit Windows machine, even if it's a 32-bit perl?

Answer (score 6):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191873/determining-64-bit-vs-32-bit-windows). You check the `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Ben S.

From the link in the question you linked to:  [msdn blog on how to dectect process bitness](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/HOWTO-Detect-Process-Bitness.aspx)

Yielded the following code:
print "WIN64?: $ENV{PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE} \n";
print "WIN64?: $ENV{PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432} \n";

And the following output (32 bit perl on xp64)

WIN64?: x86

WIN64?: AMD64

Seems if you're running a 32bit app on 64 bit win, you'll need to reference PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (($ENV{'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE'} eq "AMD64") or
    ($ENV{'PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432'} eq "AMD64")) {
   $arch = "win64";
} else {
   $arch = "win32";
}
```

Reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another method, although a bit more involved, would be to check the Windows API function `IsWow64Process`. An example of how to do this (in Delphi) is given in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436185/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-on-x64).

Answer (score 0):

```
    my @CPUIdentifierArray = split ' ', $ENV{PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER};
    my %ArcHash        = ('x86' => 32, 'AMD64' => 64, 'Intel64' => 64);
    my $Arch           = $ArcHash{$CPUIdentifierArray[0]};
```

It returns 32 or 64