# How can I use VBScript to determine whether I am running a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows OS?

Tags: windows, vbscript, 32bit-64bit

How do i detect the bitness (32-bit vs. 64-bit) of the Windows OS in VBScript?

I tried this approach but it doesn't work; I guess the (x86) is causing some problem which checking for the folder..

Is there any other alternative?

```
progFiles="c:\program files" & "(" & "x86" & ")"

set fileSys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fileSys.FolderExists(progFiles) Then    
   WScript.Echo "Folder Exists"    
End If
```

Comment: No, I think he wants to find out if he is running on a 32 or 64 bit OS. Therefore a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191873

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining 64-bit vs. 32-bit Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191873/determining-64-bit-vs-32-bit-windows)

Comment: @Treb: There's no VBScript answer. On second thought, it's probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556283/how-do-i-check-if-wscript-cscript-runs-on-x64-host-os

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can query the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`. A described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx), you have to add some extra checks, because the value of `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` will be `x86` for any 32-bit process, even if it is running on a 64-bit OS. In that case, the variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` will contain the OS bitness. Further details in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
Dim WshShell
Dim WshProcEnv
Dim system_architecture
Dim process_architecture

Set WshShell =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshProcEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")

process_architecture= WshProcEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE") 

If process_architecture = "x86" Then    
    system_architecture= WshProcEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432")

    If system_architecture = ""  Then    
        system_architecture = "x86"
    End if    
Else    
    system_architecture = process_architecture    
End If

WScript.Echo "Running as a " & process_architecture & " process on a " _ 
    & system_architecture & " system."
```

Comment: I have to add a quite important note to this... If you run a 32-bit CMD shell and you run the 64-bit wscript/cscript executables inside that shell, this check in your code correctly returns `x86`. HOWEVER if you are going to load COM DLLs or similar inside your code, the host loads them as if they were 64-bit DLLs. I spent four hours banging my head against this before i tested the command manually and it worked, and i knew something was off.

Answer (score 23):

Came up against this same problem at work the other day. Stumbled on this genius piece of vbscript and thought it was too good not to share.

```
Bits = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth
```

Source: http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/csi-getosbits

Comment: +1.49 - nice solution - but - alas - works on WMI time (measured in cups of tea).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a pair of VBScript functions based on the very concise answer by @Bruno:

```vb
Function Is32BitOS()
    If GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth _
       = 32 Then
        Is32BitOS = True
    Else
        Is32BitOS = False
    End If
End Function

Function Is64BitOS()
    If GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth _
       = 64 Then
        Is64BitOS = True
    Else
        Is64BitOS = False
    End If
End Function
```

**UPDATE:** Per the advice from @Ekkehard.Horner, these two functions can be written more succinctly [using single-line syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5h27x7e9.aspx) as follows:

```vb
Function Is32BitOS() : Is32BitOS = (GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth = 32) : End Function

Function Is64BitOS() : Is64BitOS = (GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth = 64) : End Function
```

*(Note that the parentheses that surround the `GetObject(...) = 32` condition are not necessary, but I believe they add clarity regarding operator precedence. Also note that the single-line syntax used in the revised implementations avoids the use of the `If/Then` construct!)*

**UPDATE 2:** Per the additional feedback from @Ekkehard.Horner, some may find that these further revised implementations offer both conciseness and enhanced readability:

```vb
Function Is32BitOS()
    Const Path = "winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'"
    Is32BitOS = (GetObject(Path).AddressWidth = 32)
End Function

Function Is64BitOS()
    Const Path = "winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'"
    Is64BitOS = (GetObject(Path).AddressWidth = 64)
End Function
```

Comment: Poeple paid by LOC or hour will like this; all other will recognize "Function F() : If Condition Then F = True Else F = False : End Function" as adiposity.

Comment: The lean version would be: "Function F() : F = Condition : End Function" - no ternary operator, no pondering whether the assignments are switched, and 4 lines less.

Comment: A conditional expression (e.g. "GetObject(...).AdressWidth = 64" evaluates to a boolean value that can be assigned without further ado to the function name (VBScript's way of return something from a function).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21484/discussion-between-ekkehard-horner-and-davidrr)

Comment: +1 for the lean version (which is just as lean if you use 3 lines; the point is the direct assignment of the conditional expression('s result) to the function name).

Answer (score 5):

WMIC queries may be slow. Use the environment strings:

```
Function GetOsBits()
   Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   If shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%") = "AMD64" Then
      GetOsBits = 64
   Else
      GetOsBits = 32
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Determining if the CPU is 32-bit or 64-bit is easy but the question asked is how to determine if the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit. When a 64-bit Windows is running, the *ProgramW6432* environment variable is defined.

This:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("PROCESS")("ProgramW6432") = ""
```

will return true for a 32-bit OS and false for a 64-bit OS and will work for all version of Windows including very old ones.

Comment: so if you run vbs by itself it would use 32-bit script by default so you have to use C:\Windows\Syswow64\cscript to run this and then it would return 64-bit

Comment: You bring a good point. Honestly I used this technique and it worked well on Windows 2000, XP 32-bit, Windows 7, 8 and 10 but I have not tested it on all OSes. So ... it is a simple solution that may not work on all version of Windows like Server 2003.

Comment: I found a simple solution just look to C:\windows\syswow64\cacript exists if it doesn’t it’s 32bit

Comment: @seanClt: `%windir%\SysWow64\CScript` exists... except when you are running on a stripped version of x64 Windows where the WoW64 system is not present: like Windows PE, Server Core when `WoW64-Support` is removed, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Addendum to Bruno's answer: You may want to check the OS rather than the processor itself, since you could install an older OS on a newer CPU:

```
strOSArch = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem=@").OSArchitecture
```

Returns string "32-bit" or "64-bit".

Comment: Addendum to Addendum: `.OSArchitecture` doesn't exist on XP.

Comment: It can return "64 bits", maybe "64 bit", depending on the localization.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check if folder `C:\Windows\sysnative` exist. This folder (or better alias) exist only in 32-Bit process, see [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector)

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

If fso.FolderExists(wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%") & "\sysnative" ) Then
    WScript.Echo "You are running in 32-Bit Mode"
Else
    WScript.Echo "You are running in 64-Bit Mode"
End if
```

Note: this script shows whether your current **process** is running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode - it does not show the architecture of your Windows.

Comment: sysnative does not exist in non-updated 64-bit XP/2003.

Comment: How old is XP/2003? 20 years?

Answer (score 0):

```
' performance should be good enough
' Example usage for console:
' CSript //NoLogo *ScriptName*.vbs
' If ErrorLevel 1 Echo.Win32
' VBScript:
On Error Resume Next
Const TargetWidth = 32
Set WMI = GetObject("winMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set Query = WMI.ExecQuery("SELECT AddressWidth FROM Win32_Processor")
For Each Item in Query
  If Item.AddressWidth = TargetWidth Then
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
Next
WScript.Quit 0
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using environment. Tested in XP, but I can't find a 32 bit CPU to test...

```
   function getbitsos()
      with WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").environment("PROCESS")
        if .item("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE") ="X86" and .item("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432") =vbnullstring Then
          getbitsos=array(32,32,32)
        elseif .item("PROGRAMFILES(x86)")=vbnullstring Then 
          getbitsos=array(64,32,32)
        elseif .item("PROGRAMFILES(x86)")=.item("PROGRAMFILES") Then
          getbitsos=array(64,64,32)
        Else
          getbitsos=array(64,64,64)
        end if   
      end with
    end function
    
    a=getbitsos()
    wscript.echo "Processor " &a(0) & vbcrlf & "OS "  & a(1) &vbcrlf& "Process " & a(2)& vbcrlf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same proposed solution in Microsoft blog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/howto-detect-process-bitness

tested in XP 32 and win7 64 (using a 32 bit and 64 bit CMD)

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
os_bit = 64
arch = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%")
archW6432 = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%")
If LCase(arch) = "x86" Then
    If archW6432 = "" Or LCase(archW6432) = "%processor_architew6432%" Then
        os_bit = 32
    End If
End If

WScript.Echo "Operating System Bit: " & os_bit
```